# I want to multiply chart data according as array length

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I used this ,to multiply doughnut chart according as array(arr) has,but it can't change to object,(data has string type).So chart doesn't appear here..,how fix it

```
   var arr=['HTML','CSS','JS'],i,data;  
   data ='[';
   for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){        
              if(i==arr.length-1){              
                                 data+='{value:"300",color:"#fff",highlight:"#aaa",label:arr[i]}';
                                 }
                             else{
                                data+='{value:"300",color:"#fff",highlight:"#aaa",label:arr[i]},';
                                 }
                         }
  data += ']';

 var dat = data;
window.onload = function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");                         
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(dat,{
                                              responsive: true,
                                                       });      
                            };
```

//want like this

dat =[{value:"300",color:"#fff",highlight:"#aaa",label:"HTML"},
                                    {value:"200",color:"#fff",highlight:"#aaa",label:"CSS"}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your array as a String.

> You need to create an array of objects [{},{},{}].
>
> The method used to INSERT a new object in an array is [PUSH()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Check the fiddle. Now it´s working OK (move the mouse on the screen to see the chart is there (you will only see it when mouse is over it):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var arr = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JS'],
    i, data;
  data = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
      data.push({
        value: "300",
        color: "#fff",
        highlight: "#aaa",
        label: arr[i]
      });

    } else {
      data.push({
        value: "300",
        color: "#fff",
        highlight: "#aaa",
        label: arr[i]
      });

    }
  }

  var dat = data;

  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(dat, {
    responsive: true,
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you ----------------@Alejandro Teixeira Munoz

Comment: You welcome, plz, mark question as solved if this is the solution!! thnks!